# Previous month datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime instance declared as follows:

```
dtDate = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1,0,0)
```

How do I get the previous month and previous year from `dtDate`?

e.g. something like:

```
dtDate.minusOneMonth()
# to return datetime.datetime(2015,12,1,0,0)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use:

```
dtDate = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1,0,0)

print (dtDate - pd.DateOffset(months=1))
2015-12-01 00:00:00

print (dtDate - pd.DateOffset(years=1))
2015-01-01 00:00:00
```

Add `s` is important, because if use `year` only:

```
print (dtDate - pd.DateOffset(year=1))
0001-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
In [32]:    
dtDate = dt.datetime(2016,1,1,0,0)
dtDate - pd.DateOffset(months=1)

Out[32]:
Timestamp('2015-12-01 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 3):

To Manipulate an entire pandas series.

Use `pd.DateOffset()` with `.dt.to_period("M")`

```
df['year_month'] = df['timestamp'].dt.to_period("M")
df['prev_year_month'] = (df['timestamp'] - pd.DateOffset(months=1)).dt.to_period("M")
```

[image]

If you want to go forward a month, set `months=-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `relativedelta` from `dateutil`:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta
dtDate = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1,0,0)
# get previous month
print ((dtDate+dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1)).month)
# get previous year
print ((dtDate+dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=-1)).year)
```

Output:

```
12
2015
```